# Class diagram for permissions

Tags: uml, requirements, class-diagram

I have this class diagram exercise in UML. The main problem was the permissions are the works, which I did not know very well how to model it. The specification says:

> Users can publish their work on a website for external users. In this
>   process the work will be equipped with a Web service interface.
>
> The environment will have a Web system so that users outside the
>   company can simulate simulation work for a fee. Web users must
>   identify themselves to access the different works.
>
> External users may request permission to simulate the different works
>   on the Web system, to obtain said permission they must pay the price
>   that the company has established for each work . The system will keep
>   the date in which the simulation permission of each work was granted
>   to each external user. Once permission has been granted, external
>   users will be able to run the work as many times as necessary, the
>   system will store the number of runs of each work that each external
>   user has performed.

The solution I had raised is the following diagram:

[image]

But I have some doubts: are access permissions and external user jobs represented correctly?

Comment: You could have used your SO account here as well...

Answer (score 1):

I was taught to do it like you have back at my University. It took me years to understand why that's all wrong.

First, the "specification" is bad, even (or especially?) for an exercise. Specifications should describe the ***behavior*** of the system from the perspective of the business / users. Things like "the system will keep the date", or "system will store the number of runs" does not describe observable / business behavior. These are the kinds of things where an architect will ask: why? what is it for?

This is not a minor point. A lot of pain (i.e. unmaintainable code) comes from people not capable of distinguishing between technical and business concepts.

Second, as you might suspect at this point, classes / objects are there to implement / represent / model ***behavior*** as well. This is why a good object model will be almost homomorphic with a good specification.

What you have is a *data* model of sorts. Or some high-level concepts overview of sorts.

So if you ask whether pemissions or external jobs are modeled right, my answer is: **No**, not according to any metric I consider useful for actual software development.

Comment: I didn't dare to say: "The model is for the bin. Go to square 1."

Comment: That is the solution that I had thought most reasonable and for which I see you were also taught. Regarding point one, as it is an exercise that is already defined and is thus already by default, I cannot enter. Regarding the second point of the behavior, are you saying that it is also poorly defined to carry out the successive interaction diagrams?